# JAX RPC service returning a map like structure

Tags: jax-rpc

I do know that the hashmap data structure is not allowed in JAX-RPC webservice.

But i would like to return data which looks like this in my service.

```
Atrribute,<Key><value>,Atrribute,<Key><value>,Atrribute,<Key><value> ..
```

Any idea how would i do this please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TO Return Map like structue you need to wrap it in Wrapper class.

Wrap your Map into `JAXBMap` as shown below and return it.

```
package myexample;

import java.util.Map;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class JAXBMap<T, K> {
Map<T, K> map;

public Map<T, K> getMap() {
    return map;
}

public void setMap(Map<T, K> map) {
    this.map = map;
}

public JAXBMap(Map<T, K> map) {
    super();
    this.map = map;
}

public JAXBMap() {
    super();
}

}
```